# Suppose $g$ is a periodic function with period $k$. Let the stochastic process be defined as $X_t=g(t+T)$, where $T\sim U(0,k)$.

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Suppose $g$ is a periodic function with period $k$. Let the stochastic process be defined as $X_t=g(t+T)$, where $T\sim U(0,k)$. I'm trying to prove that $\{X_t:t \geq0\}$ is weak-sense stationary. I already proved that $\mu_X(t)=constant$, for all $t$. Now I need to prove that $R_X(t_1,t_2)$ only depends of $t_1-t_2$ or $t_2-t_1$.

By definition: $R_X(t_1,t_2)=\mathbb{E}(X_{t_{1}}X_{t_{2}})=\mathbb{E}\left[g(t_1+T)\,g(t_2+T)\right]=\frac{1}{k}\int_{0}^kg(t_1+T)\,g(t_2+T)\,dT$.

I don't know how to continue from this integral, I have tried to make variable changes and use the periodicity of $g$, but I can't get anything in particular. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can write $t$ as a shifted multiple of $k$. That is, $t = mk + t'$ for some integer $m$ and $t' \in [0,k)$. Then, $g(t + T) = g(t' + T)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $g$ is $k$-periodic (assuming that $g$ is in $L_2(0,k)$), the function $G:s\mapsto g(t_1+s)g(t_2+s)$ is also $k$ periodic and so,
\begin{align}
\int^k_0g(t_1+s)g(t_2+s)\,ds&=\int^k_0G(s)\,ds=\int^{k-t_1}_{-t_1}G(s)\,ds=\int^k_0G(s-t_1)\,ds\\
&=\int^k_0g(s)g(s+t_2-t_1)\,ds
\end{align}

That is because $\int_IG(s)\,ds=\int^k_0G(s)\,ds$ for any interval of length $k$.